# comment boxes in excel gets shrinked when new rows are added between or when the size is too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have placed some comments to some of the cells and the size of the contents goes from 20 characters to 1040 characters.

The problem comes in below scenarios
1. The comment gets shrinked and not properly displaying in the page.
2. For small texts also it gets shrinked if i add new row in between start of the page and the cell where the comment is placed.

I tried below code sample but it never worked for me

```
Sub Comments_AutoSize()
Dim MyComments As Comment
Dim lArea As Long

For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
  With MyComments
    .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
      lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
      .Shape.Width = 200
      .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 1.1
    End If
  End With
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't tried the code above but are you ensuring the activesheet is the sheet with your comments in before running? Do you receive any error messages when executing the code?

Comment: The code is working fine without any errors. But the comment is still shrinked